# remove option from second select if already selected [Ordered multiple selection]

Tags: vue.js

I had select option repeater.

What I want is that when I selected johndoe at the first option, it will no longer display on the second select option.

here's my html

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue JS Multiple Fields Repeater</h1>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default relative has-absolute" v-for="(field, index) in users.usersRepeater">
              <button @click="addUsersField" type="button">
                Add
              </button>
              <button @click="deleteUsersField(index)" v-if="field != 0" type="button">
                Delete
              </button>
              <div class="panel-body has-absolute">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="users" class="control-label col-sm-3 text-left">Users {{field}}</label>
                    <select :name="'users'+index"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="users">
                        <option value="" hidden>Select User</option>
                        <option value="1">John Doe</option>
                        <option value="2">Mark Doe</option>
                        <option value="3">Mae Doe</option>
                        <option value="4">John Smith</option>
                        <option value="5">Mae Smith</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

here's my vue.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: {
          usersRepeater: [{ user: '' }]
        }
  },
  methods: {
      addUsersField: function() {
        this.users.usersRepeater.push({
          user: ''
        });
      },
      deleteUsersField: function(index) {
        this.users.usersRepeater.splice(index, 1);
      },
  }
});
```

here's the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/0e3csn5y/23/

Comment: You shouldn't hard code the users list inside your html

Comment: maybe this will help a bit https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/2/ i can do it but i have no time now

Comment: I already updated the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/0e3csn5y/23/

Comment: create another list to keep selected users or better yet add another property to isSelected to your users list ...

Comment: This [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-libs-multi-select-with-order) might be useful for you. It looks like it does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @JSmith Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: It looks great, but i want to get the id of the corresponding value not the value itself

Answer (score 1):

**[Ok I have this working now](https://jsfiddle.net/0e3csn5y/34/).** I liked the question because making an ordered selection is a generic case. But, for me anyway, it wasn't straightforward. The breakthrough was realising that, when you number the choices, the whole state of the component could be encapsulated in one array, `allUsers`. Available users and choices then become computed properties, based on this array. Moral of the story: get your store right, with no interactions between elements of the store.

My answer weighs in at 130 lines. How long and hard would this be without Vue? Mind boggles.

Stack wants me to post some code, so here's the computed property that generates an array of choices made, in order of their priority, from the all users array...

```
choices(){
    return this.store.allUsers.map((aUser,index)=>{
    if(aUser.selection != null)
        return {idxAllUsers : index, selection: aUser.selection};
    else
        return null;
  })
  .filter(aSelection=>aSelection != null)
  .sort((a,b)=>{return a.selection - b.selection})
  .map(a=>a.idxAllUsers);
},
```

Comment: I can't add new select option

Comment: Some more updates to the fiddle. The selectedUsers array is updating, but not displaying properly yet. Monster question.

Comment: its not helpful anyway, for now

Comment: @JSmith Did you ever go forward with this? [My jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0e3csn5y/34/) solution is still working perfectly, according to me.

Answer (score -2):

I found [this one](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/) very helpful.

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).